# Scala for-comprehension and Option

Tags: scala, option-type, for-comprehension

```
object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val x = Option(2)
    val y = None // works with: Option.empty[Int]
    val z = Option(5)

    val result1 = for {
      x <- x
      y <- y
      z <- z
    } yield {
      (x, y, z, x + y + z, x * y * z)
    }

    println(result1)
  }
}
```

This code yields an exception:

```
example.scala:14: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method * in class Int of type (x: Char): Int
and  method * in class Int of type (x: Byte): Int
match argument types (Nothing)
      (x, y, z, x + y + z, x * y * z)
```

If we use `val y = Option.empty[Int]` instead of `val y = None`, it works in the sense that `result1` contains `None`.

But why are there any restrictions on the function `*` ? We don't get `(2, None, 5, None, None)` anyway. I assumed the step would be skipped if one value was `None`, so why must `*` unambiguously refer to a definition?

Comment: You almost never want to have a value whose type is `None` or `Some`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error happens because  `y` has type `None` which extends `Option[Nothing]`.

In the for comprehension, the inner `y` thus has a `Nothing` type and you cannot apply `*` to `Nothing`.

The error goes away if you explicitly type (outer) `y` to `Option[Int]`:

```scala
val y: Option[Int] = None
```

---

When you say:

> assumed the step would be skipped if one value was `None`

This is true **at runtime**, but at compile time the compiler only sees a combination of `Option[Int]` and `Option[Nothing]`.

Comment: So it seems to just work this way that you need `Option[X]`s type whenever you get the value of the option and use it in a place where type `X` is expected - the compiler doesn't have a special rule for `val`s declared as containing `None`.